# SQL select data grouped by attr1 with different criteria on attr2 and attr3

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, count

I have table with data like this in Access:

```
attr1 attr2 attr3
A     1     Yes
B     8     Yes
B     6     No
C     4     No
D     5     Yes
D     2     Yes
```

I need result grouped by attr1, count attr2 and count attr3 only if value is "Yes":

```
attr1 attr2 attr3
A     1     1
B     2     1
C     1     0
D     2     2
```

I would appreciate any help with sql.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression for the third column is the challenge here.

Consider an `IIf` expression: `IIf(m.attr3='Yes', 1, 0)`

That expression will return 1 when the field contains 'Yes', and 0 otherwise.

So use that expression in a `Sum()` function in your query.  This query returns what you requested from your sample data.

```sql
SELECT
    m.attr1,
    Count(m.attr2) AS CountOfattr2,
    Sum(IIf(m.attr3='Yes', 1, 0)) AS SumOfYes
FROM tblMario AS m
GROUP BY m.attr1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the sql and the explanation. It works!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT attr1, Count(attr2), Sum(iif(attr3 = "Yes",1,0)) FROM MyTable GROUP BY attr1 ;
```

Google 'SQL GROUP BY' and 'SQL  Aggregate functions' for more info

Comment: Thanks. I'm having trouble with this part Count(attr3 = "Yes") - it doesn't work good (at least not in Access. It counts all, not only rows with "Yes". It gives the same result as column attr2

Comment: Corrected. As HansUp says, use Sum of iif instead

Answer (score 1):

Can be done without IIF, in Access TRUE/Yes is -1 so `-1* attr3`.

```
SELECT
    m.attr1,
    Count(m.attr2) AS CountOfattr2,
    Sum(-1* attr3)  AS SumOfYes
   
FROM tblMario AS m
GROUP BY m.attr1;
```